# In Android, is it possible to get permission for class in interface 2 on a composite device

Tags: android, permissions, usb, host, composite

I have developed two usb devices of different classes that I can connect to an Android phone through a hub. They are both recognized and once permissions are granted, I can access both of them. One uses only bulk end points and the other uses only control transfers. My Android programs can talk to both of these devices without trouble.

I decided to put both functions in one usb device as a composite USB device with two interfaces. This saves real estate and power on the hardware side. This composite device connects correctly to a PC and the drivers are loaded correctly.

When I connect this composite device to Android, I can get permission for the device. Then, I can use the bulk end points that are associated with interface 1. I can read descriptors on the control interface. However, I can not read or write successfully to the class on interface 2 through the control interface.

I know that the control interface is working because I can detect the class commands from inside the firmware of the device. Therefore, it appears to be an issue of permissions.

After reading the Android documentation, I have been unable to figure out how to ask for permission for the second (and additional) interface class.

Does anyone know how to get such permission? Or perhaps I am wrong about the cause and there is a different reason for this behavior?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my issue. It did not have anything to do with Android permissions. It seems that for a composite device, you only need to get Android permission once for the "device" and it is possible to access the internal classes.

My issue was with the actual control transfer. I had set up a control write with a buffer but the response from the firmware was a ZLP. Apparently, Android waits for the buffer and times out. In doing so, it seems that subsequent control transfers fail. Once I changed the buffer to null and the buffer length to 0x0 in the control transfer call, the issue was resolved.